# Can I calculate partial density of states (PDOS) using tight binding approximation?

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states, tight-binding

I am using tight binding approximation for a 2D material by 2*2 Hamiltonian, and I have ploted the density of states correctly. Can I also calculate the partial density of states using tight binding? What is the method?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "partial density of states"? Can you please edit your question and explain this?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to obtain the bandstructure using the TB approximation by diagonalizing the hamiltonian, the calculation of DOS or PDOS is straightforward.

Technically, you need to sample the brillouin zone corresponding to your crystal symmetry : polyhedra methods or you can by yourself if your are an amateur generate the k-points as coordinates of a BZ-like structure or by a random sampling.

Once you have the k-points the DOS is simply given by $$Dos(E) \propto \sum_n \sum_k \delta (e_n(k) - E) $$ As you know how to approximate the delta function, you can calculate approximately the DOS at a given energy $E$ where $e_n(k)$ is the eigenvalue after diagonalization for  the band index $n$ and the k-point $k$.
Concerning the PDOS, you need the eigenvectors (from the diagonalization) because they have the angular momentum character of your s, p or d like bands.

$$PDOS_i(E) \propto \sum_n \sum_k \sum_j c^*_{jn}c_{in} \delta(e_n(k)-E)$$

Where the $c_{in}$ is the eigenvector for the band index $n$ and $i$ the PDOS index. This formula is for an orthogonalized basis sets. If the basis sets is non orthogonal you should add the overlap matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I distinguish which PDOS is related to which orbital?

Comment: It depends how your hamiltonian matrix is made and the row or column index of the orbitals used as basis sets. If your matrix involves s and p orbitals as basis sets ($4\times4$ in size), you will have 4 eigenvalues 1 has a s character and three have a p character depending on the index where you use s or p orbitals for the construction of H.

Comment: Thank you. My Hamiltonian is 2*2 and is related to the boron phosphide. Should I sandwich DOS between eigenstates to calculate PDOS?